# Codeigniter own library is not reading session values on first time page load

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, session-variables

I'm trying to assign client side javascript value to php session using ajax.

Following are client side code ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var timeZone = 'Asia/Kolkata';
        $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/schedule/setLocalTimeZone',
        type: 'POST',
            data: {
            timeZone: timeZone,
            },
        cache: true,
        success: function(response) {   
            //alert(response)
            }       
        }); 

      });
</script>
```

following are my controller code ,

```
function setLocalTimeZone(){
    $tz = $_REQUEST['timeZone'];

    $this->session->set_userdata('TIMEZONE',$tz);


}
```

here in controller i'm setting time zone value to php session , then i'm trying to use this session value in my own code igniter library

class TimeZone {

```
function getTimeZone(){

    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('session');
//here i'm trying to get "TIMEZONE" value from session but i couldnt get at first time when irefresh the page i can get the TIMEZONE value from session 
       $user_tz = $CI->session->userdata('TIMEZONE');

    return $user_tz;
    }
```

}

Then i'm calling this library function in view page , so first time when page loads its not giving any value when i refresh only its giving value.

```
echo $Timezone = $this->timezone->getTimeZone();
```

so i'm not getting where is the problem. whether codeigniter external library ll not read the session values thich we set through ajax call first time ??

Thank you in advance,
Dhinesh.B

Comment: you are getting values on first time refreshing page?

Comment: ya in javascript console.log i'm getting value but in from library "echo $Timezone = $this->timezone->getTimeZone();" i'm not getting value. 

Second time if i refresh i'm getting value in both js and php.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution, but try to reload page once when it loads first time.
This might be useful.

Use javascript to reload page one time.

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    (function()
    {
      if( window.localStorage )
      {
        if( !localStorage.getItem( 'firstLoad' ) )
        {
          localStorage[ 'firstLoad' ] = true;
          window.location.reload();
        }  
        else
          localStorage.removeItem( 'firstLoad' );
      }
    })();

    </script>
```

Comment: not sure, but jquery always takes value which is at first time page loading. after ajax task we are getting value perfectly , but jquery only takes new value when we reload page.